# How to return non-duplicate values of array of object

Tags: javascript

```
var newarray= 
[ { value: 'Large', name: 'Size' },
{ value: 'Red', name: 'Color' },
{ value: 'Cotton', name: 'Material' },
{ value: 'Affinity', name: 'Collection' },
{ value: 'Pine Montage', name: 'Style' },
{ value: 'Large', name: 'Size' },
{ value: 'Red', name: 'Color' },
{ value: 'Jute', name: 'Material' },
{ value: 'Affinity', name: 'Collection' },
{ value: 'Pine Montage', name: 'Style' },
{ value: 'Large', name: 'Size' },
{ value: 'Green', name: 'Color' },
{ value: 'Jute', name: 'Material' },
{ value: 'Affinity', name: 'Collection' },
{ value: 'Pine Montage', name: 'Style' } ];
```

Here is my array i need to find unique array of object with non-repeated values in an array ,Please help

Comment: So perhaps loop through the input array, adding items to another array if they're not already present? Where are you stuck?

Comment: ok let me try this ! thanks for your suggestion

Comment: can you tell me how i will compare object of new temp array and the old array

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to iterate over the array and filter the items with a look up if the item is stored in a hash map.

```js
var array = [{ value: 'Large', name: 'Size' }, { value: 'Red', name: 'Color' }, { value: 'Cotton', name: 'Material' }, { value: 'Affinity', name: 'Collection' }, { value: 'Pine Montage', name: 'Style' }, { value: 'Large', name: 'Size' }, { value: 'Red', name: 'Color' }, { value: 'Jute', name: 'Material' }, { value: 'Affinity', name: 'Collection' }, { value: 'Pine Montage', name: 'Style' }, { value: 'Large', name: 'Size' }, { value: 'Green', name: 'Color' }, { value: 'Jute', name: 'Material' }, { value: 'Affinity', name: 'Collection' }, { value: 'Pine Montage', name: 'Style' }],
    unique = function (a) {
        var o = {};
        return a.filter(function (b) {
            var k = b.name + '|' + b.value;
            if (!(k in o)) {
                o[k] = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }(array);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(unique, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for getting unique values

```
var uniq = Array.from(new Set(newarray.map(function(a) {
    return JSON.stringify(a);
}))).map(function(a) {
    return JSON.parse(a)
});

console.log(uniq); // will print your unique values
```